# The equalsIgnoreCase is not working for me while verification of 2 string value

Tags: java, string, selenium, conditional-statements, equals

The `String#equalsIgnoreCase` is not working for me while verifying 2 strings values.

**Actual:**

We encountered the following errors while processing your request: The catalog have at least one product in category: `Series (code:84155)`

**Expected:**

We encountered the following errors while processing your request: The catalog have at least one product in category: `Series (code:84155)`

The actual and expected is same but still have my program failing .I have tried using trim but it still not working:

```java
if (actualText.equalsIgnoreCase(expectedText.trim())) {}
```

Comment: `equalsIgnoreCase` works fine, debug your to see where's the problem.

Comment: try printing actual and expected text and try to see whats the difference.

Comment: try trimming the actualText string as well before comparison.

Comment: And worst case: print them character by character; sometimes strings **look** the same, but arent in reality. You see, that methods does what it is supposed to do; if it doesn't meet your expectations; than your expectations are the problem.

Comment: @ChetanHallan Probably he maybe should **only** trim the actual text. The expected text might be *constructed* somehow; and then you simply construct it without things that would require trimming.

Comment: @GhostCat true. That could be the reason (y)

Answer (score 2):

Change `if (actualText.equalsIgnoreCase(expectedText.trim()))` 
to 
 `if (actualText.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(expectedText.trim()))`

Comment: Thats just a guess so far; you have no idea if it will do the trick.

Comment: yes. it is a calculated guess. ideally he need to trim both strings.

Comment: oh.. yes. I didn't see that comment.